# Издать стандартные звуки Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, аудио

Добрый день,

Очень давно в разных система была функция beep - она не имела никаких параметров и просто издавал простейший звук. Есть ли аналоги в Андроид ? И если можно с импортом и всеми плюшками которые нужно добавить. очевидно, что для простого действия в андроид нужны сотни строк кода :) и можно ли сделать вызов стандартного звонка например ? И существует ли вызов звуков по идентификаторам - например "сыграть стандартную мелодию звонка"? Т.е. моя задача издать звук БЕЗ КАКИХ ЛИБО ФАЙЛОВ Идущих вместе с приложением, а все примеры  идут - это звук из файла mp3 что мне не подходит.

Пока только несколько дней занимаюсь Андроид, поэтому ничего "само-собой" для меня нет ....

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так в виде можно проиграть звуковой эффект:

```
view.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

Но это только звук клика. Если же нужно проиграть уведомление то все несколько сложнее:

```
try {
    Uri notify = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notify);
    r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ, ответ по сути! Добавил import uri,ringtone и все заработало.